# Как сократить долгую проверку на каждую букву C#

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Нужно сделать проверку что бы введенное слово не содержало английских символов (f,a,g). Но простым, длинным str.Contains() как-то не рационально что ли. А другие мысли не приходят в голову. Что можете посоветовать?

```
bool EngLetter( string a)
{
    if (a.Contains ('a') || a.Contains ('b') || a.Contains ('c') || a.Contains ('d') || a.Contains ('e') || a.Contains ('f') || a.Contains ('g') || a.Contains ('h')) /* ...*/
        return false;
    else
        return true;    
    }
```

Comment: Используйте словарь или что то на подобии для проверки (находится ли там этот символ или нет).

Comment: а если список??

Comment: Попробуйте Split. `Split(new char[]('a','b')) ` а лучше в константу массив положить. Вариант 2 - попробуйте прекомпилированый RegEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из самых быстрых вариантов со словарем

```
private static HashSet<char> _engLetters 
                       = new HashSet<char>() {'a', 'b', 'c' /*.....*/}; 
bool EngLetter(string a)
{
    return a.Any(c=>_engLetters.Contains(c));
}
```

Ну, или если вы ищете только англ буквы, то можно воспользоваться тем, что они идут диапазонами

```
bool EngLetter(string a)
{
    return a.Any(c =>(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'));
}
```

Comment: Странно но ни-один из Ваших 2 вариантов не роботает

Comment: А тот ответ который я отметил без изменений и роботает

Comment: @AquaGF приведите примеры того, что вы посылаете в мои варианты, что приходит из них и что вы ожидаете, что должно приходить

Comment: Ну я сделал условие что если метод (с которым я сюда пришёл) возращает true тогда выводится сообщение с ошибкой.

Comment: выводится только в его варианте

Comment: @AquaGF это мне ничего не дает. Вы говорите, что методы работают неверно, так? То есть вы знаете случай, когда конкретная строка посылается в метод, и метод возвращает не то, что вы ожидаете. Вот я и спрашиваю, что за строку вы посылаете, что ожидаете на выходе?

Comment: Секунду щас всё опишу

Comment: Всё написал в ответе

Comment: @AquaGF 1) Ваш изначальный код в вопросе и код в ответе отличаются по логике. 2) Не надо писать ответ для уточнения вопроса - просто отредактируйте вопрос. 3) Я обновил свой ответ, проверяйте

Comment: Какой из 2 ваших вариантов

Comment: Первый теперь работает

Comment: Всё теперь работает. Спасибо что провозились много ответов сразу нахлынуло сложно сориентироваться

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Добавить цикл и развернуть проверку

```
bool EngLetter(string a) {
  string match = "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz";
  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
    if (match.Сontains(a[i]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Вариант 2. Использовать регулярные выражения

```
bool EngLetter(string a) {
  Regex match = new Regex(@"[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  return !match.IsMatch(a);
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант по проще для меня. Спасибо.

Comment: Первый вариант не скомплируется, обратите внимание на эту строчку `if (match.contains(a[i]))` = там наверное должно быть `if (a.Contains(match[i]))`

Comment: Странно, у меня скомплировалось, и роботает по задумке

Comment: @AquaGF вариант 1 не скомпилируется вот тут `match.contains(..)` так как в массивах такого метода нет. Но если это исправить и вызвать вот так `EngLetter(";3453453");` - то оно скомпилируется, но упадет

Comment: Я бы в вариант 2 добавил опцию - прекомпилированое.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за уточнение. Там должно быть `i < a.Length`. `match` это не массив, а строка

Comment: Да в строке тоже такого метода нет :)

Comment: ну, и ещё я бы обратил ваше внимание на время работы вашего алгоритма, что первого, что второго. Вариант даже с простым hashset по идее будет работать примерно в 30 раз быстрее, так как `match.Contains` скорее всего линейная операция, а не константная, а регулярки сами по себе очень медленные.

Comment: @tym32167 а c# не кастует сам char к string? Никогда на c# не работал

Comment: char к string нет, не кастует

Comment: @tym32167 добавил `toString()`

Comment: нет, этого не надо. Просто оставьте как `if (match.Contains(a[i]))`, так как вы используете вот [этот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) метод - он доступен как метод расширения поскольку `string` реализует `IEnumerable<char>` интерфейс, то нет необходимости приводить параметр к string

Comment: @tym32167 вы же сами говорили, что работать не будет

Comment: Я говорил только про опечатку `match.contains` => `match.Contains` - просил сделать первую букву заглавной, так как C# чувствителен к регистру с метод  `match.contains` он не найдет, а вот метод `match.Contains` - найдет.